# Is there any way to change field label character limit in salesforce?

Tags: fields

I am not able to add field label more than 40 characters, because of salesforce limitations is there any workaround for this.

Comment: Nope -- creative abbreviations or even the use of emojis might help

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible.

Workaround would depend on your business scenario.

Please see the [existing idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdeTIUAZ/increase-field-label-character-limits).